# #DocuSignAPI Initial Here tab json format

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

For SIGN HERE TAB working functionality we were sending:

```
"tabs":{"signHereTabs":    [{"tabLabel":"JOINT_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1","recipientId":"3"}],"dateSignedTabs":    [{"tabLabel":"JOINT_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignDateSigned","recipientId":"3"}]}
```

But in similar format we are sending JSON for INITIAL HERE TAB functionality which is not working.
We are sending the following format :

```
"tabs":{"initialHereTabs":[{"tabLabel":"JOINT_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1","recipientId":"3"}],"dateSignedTabs":[{"tabLabel":"JOINT_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignDateSigned","recipientId":"3"}]}
```

and it is instead pulling full sign rather than initial when clicking the sign mark on the document.

Why it is not pulling Initial sign on clicking sign mark?

Comment: How you are adding tabs on the document for a recipient, I am seeing any X and Y position nor I am seeing Anchor String? Are you using pdf form field transformation concept?

Comment: No we are not, we are just sending the payload which is having the JSON request alongwith PDF docs to be signed to DocuSign. Docusign populate the signature place with a kind of mark, clicking that mark pulling Full Signature instead of Initial despite JSON having "initialHereTabs".

Comment: Can you please share the full JSON request, instead of just `tabs` node, its easy to replicate the issue which you are seeing, if possible share your PDF as well. Its seems you are using `"transformPdfFields":"true"` in your `document` node.

Comment: Yah, we are using transformPdfFields parameter, see below:

"document":{"documentId":"503626","name":"Investor Profile:x.pdf","transformPdfFields":"true"}

Comment: Amit K Bist : Could u please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

When using PDF and `"transformPdfFields":"true"`, then DocuSign follows below rules to convert PDF fields to DocuSign tabs automatically. In your case if you want Initial DocuSign tabs to appear on DocuSign then change the PDF Form field name to something like DocuSignInitialHere or eSignInitialHere, and DocuSign will automatically place the Initial Tab on the envelope's document. More details are available at [DS Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) - `PDF Form Field Transformation` section

[image]

Comment: Amit K Bist : We are tagging 'eSignInitialHere' on the PDF field name like below:
"PRIMARY_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignInitialHere"
and getting the below JSON also:

"tabs":{"initialHereTabs":[{"tabLabel":"PRIMARY_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignInitialHere","recipientId":"2"}],"dateSignedTabs":[{"tabLabel":"PRIMARY_OWNER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignInitialHere_eSignDateSigned","recipientId":"2"}]}

"document":{"documentId":"513179","name":"Investor Profile Questionnaire_Deferred Annuity:4655152F6922_f1_s.pdf","transformPdfFields":"true"}},

But docuSign still pulling Full Sign instead of Initial sign.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send your PDF doc to my email - docusign.sso@gmail.com after removing all PII data from the doc.

Comment: Amit K Bist  : I already sent you a PDF on email - docusign.sso@gmail.com, please lemme know what do you think of it now?

Comment: Let me check my email and get back to you

Comment: Amit K BIst : Did you find anyting?

Comment: I did not get chance to check your file, will check once I am done with my work